# Resources for handwritten scientific notes?

Tags: resource-recommendation

I am interested in looking at the notebooks, manuscripts, and letters of scientists and mathematicians from history. It is usually possible to search for a particular person, but tracking images and PDFs from many different sources can be time consuming. So, I'm looking for resource recommendations for browsing handwritten or typed informal sentiments and notes from historical scientists and mathematicians. Both online resources, and physical archives in my region (Philadelphia area), would be very useful.

For example: Michael Faraday wrote numerous letters, and his notes on chemistry have been digitized and assembled with transcriptions, into a book which is also available online. However, it is difficult to find an indexed list which allows one to search for different topics. Most scientists are much more difficult to track down than Faraday as well, e.g. Laplace, Poisson, Legendre, Riemann, Hamilton, Ampere, Maxwell, Coulomb, Hertz, etc.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is a systematic way to search for handwritten manuscripts, and they are rarely available on the web. One collection is here:
http://www.claymath.org/node/1370
If you press on the pop-up menu "Publications" in the top, you find
manuscripts of Klein, Quillen, Riemann and others.
University of Uppsala has Beurling's archive:
http://www.math.uu.se/beurling/

Answer (score 1):

Dirac Shoebox Collection at Florida State University contains various handwritted notes by Paul Dirac. A part of it is available online: https://fsu.digital.flvc.org/islandora/object/fsu%3Amarksstaging